# Can we span the SQL server to multiple machines

Tags: sql-server

When the database is becoming huge, how to divide it and span to multiple servers?

Comment: when you say 'when the database is becoming huge' do you mean there is too much to store and so you want to split it, or that there are too many connections and you want to replicate the db across multiple  servers to ease the load?

Comment: I think we need more information.  I've worked on multi-terabyte database that reside on single sql server.  Not that it wasn't clusted and replicated and all that, but i could access all data from a single machine.  What's huge?  Number of tables?  gigs/terabytes?  number of users/reads/ queries?

Answer (score 1):

How huge? Single instance SQL Server deployments are [capable of handling peta-byte databases](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2008/nov08/11-06AlzHeavensPR.mspx?rss_fdn=Press%20Releases).

For scale-out one option to look at is [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx), which can do an in-place scale-out of an application not explicitly designed for such.

Applications that are designed for scale-out ahead of time have more options, for instance consider how MySpace [spans over individual 1000 databases by using a message buss](http://www.slideshare.net/markginnebaugh/myspace-sql-server-service-broker-oct-2009).

For more specific answers, you have to provide more specific details about your real case.